# jQuery toggle tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am nesting tables within tables and want to toggle the them when you click on a `<th class="folder">`

```
    $('table').each(function(){
        $('th.folder', this).bind('click', function(){
            $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').toggle();
        });
    });
```

Here is some typical HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th class="type">Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="folder" colspan="2">Deal flow</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>item 1</td>
              <td>image</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>item 2</td>
              <td>image</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="folder" colspan="2">Rejected deals</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>item 3</td>
              <td>image</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>item 4</td>
              <td>image</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why! Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [See Working Example](http://jsbin.com/avuro3)

---

Try this instead:

```
  $('.folder').bind('click', function(){
     $(this).closest('table').children('tbody').toggle();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context is wrong, try just $('th.folder');
Also, I would use live() instead of bind() since live() is faster.

Comment: You should not choose `live` over `bind` everywhere. `live` has significant downsides, too.

Comment: yes I know, like bubbling for example. But I don't see how that could be a problem here :)